# Configure zero-to-one relationship wih E.F. Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing a C# library with .Net Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

This is what I'm trying to design:

I have one code that can have one helper code or not. In other words, a code can have zero or one helper code.

And also, I could have helper codes that are not related to any code.

These are the POCOs classes:

```
public class HelperCode
{
    public int HelperCodeId { get; set; }

    [ ... ]

    public virtual Code Code { get; set; }
}

public class Code
{
    public int CodeId { get; set; }

    [ ... ]

    public int? HelperCodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual HelperCode HelperCode { get; set; }
}
```

Yes, I know, I have another question with the same issue. Well, it is not the same question because the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32646139/68571) doesn't work:

```
class CodeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Code>
{
  public CodeConfiguration()
 {

  //other codes      

    HasOptional(c => c.HelperCode)
        .WithRequired(hc => hc.Code).HasForginKey(x=>x.HelperCodeId);
  }
}
```

Because it is not required to have a code and .WithRequired() doesn't have .ForeignKey().

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 this type of relationship is modeled with [Shared Primary Key Association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations).

Start by removing the `HelperCodeId` member from `Code` entity because there will not be FK from `Code` to `HelperCode`. Instead, `HelperCodeId` in `HelperCode` entity will be both PK and FK to `Code`.

Then change the `Code` entity configuration as follows:

```
HasOptional(c => c.HelperCode)
    .WithRequired(hc => hc.Code)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Why do I have to use `WillCascadeOnDelete()`.

Comment: Because by default it is off for such relationship. It allows you to delete a `Code` that has related `HelperCode`.